# Skaffold and mutiple Sub Charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm, skaffold, google-cloud-code

lately I was experimenting with Skaffold with our Helm Charts and I am in little bit in a dilemma that our Helm Chart \ Sub Charts are compatible with Skaffold or not.

Our helm Charts are looking like the following

```
my-helm-charts
+-charts
  +-project1
  +-project2
  +-project3
  +-project4
  +-infrastructure_kafka
    +-charts
      +-kafka
      +-zookeeper
  +-infrastructure_cassandra
  +-infrastructure_elasticsearch
  +-Charts.yaml
  +-Values.yaml
```

The reason we choosed to structure the Helm Charts this way, is that if necessary to spin up extra stages for our project.

Now when I want to develop project2 with Google Cloud Code / Skaffold (which I configured correctly and I can start without problem in IntelliJ) I have to start whole my-helm-charts.

That is actually Ok but the problem is, if I use Debug in Kubernetes, I have a feeling Google Cloud Code/Skaffold can really locate the project2 and no debugging occurs.

My feeling is Google Cloud/Skaffold is more oriented to work with following contruct...

```
project2-helm
+-templates
+-Charts.yaml
+-Values.yaml
```

My Subcharts contructs starts in Google Cloud Code/Skaffold without any exception but I can't debug, is it possible to achieve want I want with my structure and if yes, how?

Or is it not possible at all...

Thx for answers...

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by _"and no debugging occurs."_?  Does the debugger fail to connect?  Do breakpoints not get triggered (likely your source mapping paths don't match)?  And are you using VS Code or IDEA/IntelliJ?

Comment: I am using IntellJ and yes I don't get any hits to my Breakpoints

Comment: And what language are you using? Java?

Comment: Yes I am using Java

Comment: Could you please enable DEBUG logging level for Skaffold in your IntelliJ Cloud Code Kubernetes run configuration advanced settings and paste or attach the resulting logs when you Debug on Kubernetes? The debug level logs will have more information on debugging setup.

Answer (score 0):

We recently added a feature called config dependencies which might help here. It allows you to create more specific skaffold.yamls and then map them together with a "requires" field:
https://skaffold.dev/docs/design/config/#configuration-dependencies

Once you have the skaffold.yamls created and the right dependency mapping you can run skaffold with the -m flag to choose once slice of your services:

`skaffold dev -m project3`

Cloud Code support for modules is incoming.

Comment: Cool, any ETA for Cloud Code release with multi modules?

Comment: Please see below, the IntelliJ is released, and VS Code coming next month.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Code IntelliJ and Cloud Code VS Code recently added preview level support for deploying and debugging modules of a larger application which uses Skaffold. See more here https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/skaffold-modules